# adding a custom grunt task to sails.js

Tags: typescript, gruntjs, sails.js, grunt-ts

I'm new to sails.js but I've been reading a bunch of the documentation for the last couple of days so I feel like I have a basic grasp on the platform. But I can't seem to get custom grunt tasks added and registered.  I've tried a few ways and none of them seem to work. So I figured I'd keep it simple and just register a task with one of the existing register files, but I'm still not about to get this method to work.

So I've added the following Gruntfile to tasks/config/comp.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.config.set('comp', {
        dev: {
            options: {
                module: 'system',
                moduleResolution: 'node',
                target: 'es3',
                experimentalDecorators: true,
                emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
                noImplicitAny: false
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'assets/js/',
                src: [ '**/*.ts' ],
                dest: '.tmp/public/js',
                ext: '.js'
            }]
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ts');
};
```

And I added the following line to tasks/register/compileAssets.js

```
/**
 * `compileAssets`
 *
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This Grunt tasklist is not designed to be used directly-- rather
 * it is a helper called by the `default`, `prod`, `build`, and
 * `buildProd` tasklists.
 *
 * For more information see:
 *   http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/tasks/register/compile-assets-js
 *
 */
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.registerTask('compileAssets', [
    'clean:dev',
    'jst:dev',
    'less:dev',
    'copy:dev',
    'coffee:dev',
    'comp:dev'
  ]);
};
```

However whenever I run `sails lift` I get the following error

> info: Starting app...
>
> info:
>   info:                .-..-.
>   info:
>   info:    Sails              <|    .-..-.
>   info:    v0.12.13            |\
>   info:                       /|.\
>   info:                      / || \
>   info:                    ,'  |'  \
>   info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
>   info:                 `--'-------'
>   info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
>   info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
>   info:
>   info: Server lifted in`C:\Users\josh\Documents\PGW`
>   info: To see your app, visit http://localhost:1337
>   info: To shut down Sails, press  + C at any time.
>
> debug: -------------------------------------------------------
>   debug: :: Thu Jun 08 2017 16:32:01 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
>
> debug: Environment : development
>   debug: Port        : 1337
>   debug: -------------------------------------------------------
>   error: ** Grunt :: An error occurred. **
>
> ### error:
>
> Aborted due to warnings.
>
> ### Warning: Task "comp:dev" not found.
>
> error: Looks like a Grunt error occurred--
>   error: Please fix it, then **restart Sails** to continue running tasks (e.g. watching for changes in assets)
>   error: Or if you're stuck, check out the troubleshooting tips below.
>
> error: Troubleshooting tips:
>   error:
>   error:  *-> Are "grunt" and related grunt task modules installed locally?  Run `npm install` if you're not sure.
>   error:
>   error:  *-> You might have a malformed LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript file, etc.
>   error:
>   error:  *-> Or maybe you don't have permissions to access the `.tmp` directory?
>   error:      e.g., `C:\Users\josh\Documents\PGW\.tmp` ?
>   error:
>   error:      If you think this might be the case, try running:
>   error:      sudo chown -R YOUR_COMPUTER_USER_NAME C:\Users\josh\Documents\PGW.tmp

I've been banging my head against this for hours and I don't understand why `sails lift` won't run my task. I feel like I've followed the directions well between reading the sails docs and other stackoverflow articles. Can someone help me understand what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run the `comp` target you have defined but grunt is finding no associated `comp` *taskname --> grunt plugin* mapping to execute it.

Looks like you are attempting to use `grunt-ts`

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ts');
```

Which adds the `ts` task. Change 'comp' to `ts` in your target defintion:

```
grunt.config.set('ts', {
```

And update the compileAssets.js file

```
 grunt.registerTask('compileAssets', [
        'clean:dev',
        'jst:dev',
        'less:dev',
        'copy:dev',
        'coffee:dev',
        'ts:dev' //execute grunt-ts
      ]);
```

This should be enough to fix. If you still have issues make sure you have `grunt-ts` installed:

```
npm install grunt-ts
```

If you really want to statically map a taskname to a plugin you could use something like jit-grunt to do this for you:

```
require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
      comp: 'grunt-ts', //comp now maps to grunt-ts plugins
});
```

Comment: This answer is correct, I found it out shortly after posting my original question. But now, i'm trying to figure out how I would have known to add a task specifically called ts. I'm new to grunt as well, so I guess I'm just figuring out what the difference between the grunt init syntax I saw on the grunt-ts npm page and what I'd put in for sails. Thanks again for your help.